# Como salvar e exportar um objeto no console do navegador?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, objetos, console, automatização

no site da Caixa, os resultados das loterias são exibidos no console em forma de objetos.

http://loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias/landing/megasena/

Eu posso dar um right-click na linha Object, na qual consta todos os dados do concurso, e, depois, clicar em "Store as global variables".

Uma variável com o nome de "temp1" é criada.

Depois, eu posso exportar tais dados dando outro right-click em temp1 e clicando em "Save as...".

Daí, é gerado um arquivo externo que eu posso importar depois.

Bom, o que eu gostaria é de automatizar esse processo através de linhas de comando.

Seja através desse meio, de armazenar e salvar, ou através de algum outro que vocês creem ser mais simples e eficaz.

Enfim, podem me dar uma ajuda?

Obrigado!!!

Comment: Não sei se isso é considerado legal

Answer (score 2):

Respondendo à pergunta de "**Utilizando apenas comandos (sem mouse) salvar uma variável ou objeto do console em um arquivo**", você pode importar (ou colar) o código abaixo no próprio console e pode usar o comando `console.save()`, passando como 
primeiro parâmetro a variável/objeto e o path do arquivo de destino no segundo parâmetro.

```
(function(console){

console.save = function(data, filename){

    if(!data) {
        console.error('Console.save: No data')
        return;
    }

    if(!filename) filename = 'console.json'

    if(typeof data === "object"){
        data = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 4)
    }

    var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'text/json'}),
        e    = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'),
        a    = document.createElement('a')

    a.download = filename
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    a.dataset.downloadurl =  ['text/json', a.download, a.href].join(':')
    e.initMouseEvent('click', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null)
    a.dispatchEvent(e)
 }
})(console)
```

Exemplo de uso (no console do firefox/chrome):

```
var a1 = "aaaaaaaaaaaaa";
console.save(a1, "/home/myUser/saida.txt");
```

Comment: Muito bom! Mas, qual seria o comando pra automatizar o "Store as global variables" também!?

Answer (score 1):

Existe uma **API** que te retorna os resultados de algumas loterias em **JSON** com isso você consegue integrar em praticamente qualquer aplicação (ai vai da sua necessidade).

### Esse é o link dela junto com a ducumentação:

https://confiraloterias.com.br/api/megasena/

### Exemplo de input:

http://confiraloterias.com.br/api0/json.php?loteria=megasena&token=r9hFuFEvYXiZUuj&concurso=2062

### Retorno

```
{
"concurso": {
    "numero": "2062",
    "data": "25/07/2018",
    "cidade": "POUSO REDONDO, SC",
    "local": "Caminhão da Sorte",
    "valor_acumulado": "0,00",
    "dezenas": [
        "08",
        "10",
        "15",
        "23",
        "25",
        "34"
    ],
"premiacao": {
    "sena": {
        "ganhadores": "1",
        "valor_pago": "73.450.153,75"
        },
    "quina": {
        "ganhadores": "192",
        "valor_pago": "27.128,74"
        },
    "quadra": {
        "ganhadores": "13804",
        "valor_pago": "539,04"
        }
    },
        "arrecadacao_total": "90.343.582,00"
        },
    "proximo_concurso": {
        "data": "28/07/2018",
        "valor_estimado": "3.000.000,00"
    },
    "valor_acumulado_final_cinco": "15.139.880,89",
    "valor_acumulado_final_zero": "0,00",
    "mega_virada_valor_acumulado": "40.957.415,53",
    "resultado_completo": "1"
    }
```

Comment: Reynaldo coloca o código ao invés da imagem, imagens como código pode dificultar a indexação do conteúdo por motores de busca e atrapalhar quem for utilizar o código.

Comment: Reynaldo, agradeço o esclarecimento! Conheço essa API e eu poderia usá-la. Mas tenho que carregar de outras loterias também para qual esse site não oferece suporte. Ou seja, vou precisar aprender a buscar os dados no console mesmo! Daí a razão do post...